# How to convert string with Unicode characters to normal String?

Tags: android, string, unicode

Where I fail ?

I have incoming String from server with value "*%u0419%u043E*".

I try to convert it to normal String, but I see *chinese* letters. And it is error because incoming letter is cyrillic.

Code :

```
// String test = ""%u0419%u043E"; <--- this is Йо ( cyrillic )
byte[] test = { (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x75, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x31, (byte) 0x39,(byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x75, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x33, (byte) 0x45};
String aaa = new String(test, "UTF-16");
aaa = new String(test, "UTF-8");
aaa = new String(test, "ISO-8859-5");
```

The image explains what I do :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not a standard encoding, at least not one of the UTF-* or ISO-*.

You need to decode it yourself, e.g.

```
public static String decode(String encoded) {
    // "%u" followed by 4 hex digits, capture the digits
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%u([0-9a-f]{4})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(encoded);
    StringBuffer decoded = new StringBuffer(encoded.length());

    // replace every occurrences (and copy the parts between)
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(decoded, Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16)));
    }

    m.appendTail(decoded);
    return decoded.toString();
}
```

This gives :

```
System.out.println(decode("%u0419%u043E"));
Йо
```

Comment: How to replace if full incoming string containt %20 ?

Example : "%u0419%u043E%20"

Comment: `%XX` seems to be the standard URL encoding, so you can use `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(someString, "UTF-8")`. If the string contains both `%uXXXX` and `%XX` you must do the custom decoding first (it will leave URL encoded characters untouched)

Comment: Yes, I use the same way as above in your answer : after first decode I use new pattern **%([0-f]{2})** and new matcher. 

Question is closed